# check if the system is down or not

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

this is the script I wrote to check whether a system with the given IP is up or down in Linux:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
clear
x=`date`
read -p "please enter ip:" ip
ping -c1 $ip>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [$?!= 0]; then
  echo $ip on $x | mail -s "server is down…" admin
else
  echo "server is up"
fi
```

I want to edit this for PowerShell so, this is my code:

```bsh
$x = date
$IP = Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter IP"
ping $IP -n 1 > null 2>&1
if ($? -ne 0) {
    echo "$IP the server is Down on $x"
} else {
    echo "everything is fine"
}
```

but it always outputs `"the server is Down"` regardless of what the IP is.

Comment: This works in batch as you have tagged your question. `ping 127.0.0.1 && Echo Sucess || Echo Fail`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) indicating whether or not the last PowerShell statement was executed successfully. Its value is either `$true` or `$false`. A comparison `$true -ne 0` in PowerShell evaluates to `$true`, because the second operand is cast to a type matching the first operand. 0 cast to bool becomes `$false` ([see here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/)), and `$true -ne $false` evaluates to `$true`.

If you want to check the exit code of an external program you need to use a different automatic variable (`$LastExitCode`) instead of `$?`:

```
ping $IP -n 1 > null 2>&1
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0 ) {
...
```

However, since you're writing PowerShell anyway I'd recommend dropping the external command entirely and using `Test-Connection` instead:

```
if (Test-Connection $IP -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    'everything is fine'
} else {
    "$IP the server is down on $(Get-Date)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can allso try using the in-built "test-connection" in powershell :)

```
$computer = Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter IP"
test-connection $computer -Count 1 | Select Address,IPv4Address,ResponseTime,BufferSize
```

Comment: so how does this provide any more information than the accepted answer?